# Ruby rails - select only few columns from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

What is the way in Rails to structure SQL query to only select certain columns from the database, I have some large data fields which I want to avoid loading from continuous periodic Ajax calls. Reading unnecessarily is resource consuming and slow.

```
@itemlist = Item.find(:all, :conditions => { .... } ) #this select all columns
```

I am looking for `SELECT name, address FROM users;` instead of `SELECT * FROM users;`

Comment: Usually if you don't need/use other columns, you should think about data normalization.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Rails 3:

`Item.select("name, address").where( .... )`

Comment: Yup, great one! Promote this one, guys, as Rails 3 is far more popular than the 2nd one

Comment: Also of note, if you have more than one table in your `SELECT` statement and you're referencing a column that could exist in more than 1 table, include the table in the select, like `select("items.name, users.address")`.

Comment: Still works in Rails 7.

Answer (score 30):

Make use of `:select` construct. Try this:

```
@itemlist = Item.select('name, address', conditions: { .... } )
```

For previous version of Rails:

```
@itemlist = Item.find(:all,:select => 'name, address', :conditions => { .... } )
```

Comment: This is no longer correct and is not supported in Rails 4. Answer needs updating.

Comment: The answer has been updated after superluminary's comment to reflect the new .select syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Using Arel (aka in Rails 3), use:

```
Item.where(...).select("name, address")
```

Also, it seems .select gets ignored if you tack on a scope that has an :include => ...

Answer (score 7):

```
@itemlist = Item.select('name, address').where(...#some condition)
```

Answer (score 7):

If want to select specific columns from the `rails console`, `pluck(` will work.
Example:

```
2.4.1 :007 > User.connection
2.4.1 :006 > User.all.pluck(:email)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.`email` FROM `users`
 => ["test@test.com", "another_test@test.com"]
```

Note that this will also work from within the Rails app.

Comment: I believe you can just use `User.pluck(:email)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@itemlist = Item.find(:all, :select => "name, address", :conditions => { .... } )
```