# Rails get the specify fields of a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in my rails app:`Mem` and  `Team`. One `team` has many `mems`.

As we all know,if I just want to get the field `id` in `team`,I will write:

```
Team.select('id')
```

If I want to get the `team` of  a `mem`, I will write:

```
Mem.find(1).team
```

Now I want to get the team id and name, so I write:

```
Mem.find(1).team.select('id,name')
```

I got an error.

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
team = Mem.find(1).team.select('id,name')

team_id   = team.id
team_name = team.name
```

You may want to see this
[Ruby rails - select only few columns from the data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256390/ruby-rails-select-only-few-columns-from-the-data-base)

Comment: The result is `Mem.find(1).team` didn't has the `select` method!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a SQL query with a model attribute. `Team.select('id')` is the first part of a query that will return the id of whatever team you are looking for. If you want to get the id of a team model, you just write `team.id`, so your code should be `mem.team.id`, where `mem` is a model from the `Mem` class and `team` is a model from the `Team` class.

Let me expound a little. You need some piece of information that is unique to your model in order to retrieve your model from the database. I am going to assume that you will be using the `id`, but you can use any attribute or combinations of attributes.

Let's retrieve our models from the database:

```
star_player = Mem.find('5')
team_id = star_player.team.id
```

Two queries were executed, one that retrieved your team member using `find` and another to retrieve the team id was performed automatically using the rails associations that you should have set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,maybe the fields is not just `id`,maybe some fields just like `name`,`dt`.