# How to find a record by id and select few columns, ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a `User` model that has all the queried fields with the existing data in the database. When I execute the following query-

```
@user = User.find(4, :select => 'user_fname, user_lname')
```

Rails throws the following error for the above line

> Couldn't find all Users with 'user_id': (4, {:select=>"user_fname, user_lname"}) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)

What's going wrong?

Comment: you can try this `@user = User.where("id = ?, 4).select( "user_fname, user_lname")`

Comment: what do you want the query to return?

Comment: @Ian Root I wanted it to return only the specified columns for the given id.

Comment: which rails version you are using?

Comment: @AmitSharma - I'm using the 4.2.1 version of Rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. I hope this will help.

```
@user = User.where("id = ?", 4).select( "user_fname, user_lname")
```

Answer (score 3):

**Rails 4 :** use **[pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)** as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without loading a bunch of records just to grab the attributes you want.

Try:

```
> User.where(id: 4).pluck(:user_fname , :user_lname).first
#=> ["John", "Smith"] # this is just sample of output
```

Comment: Thanks! that looks like a cleaner option

Answer (score 0):

You are using `#find` incorrectly. It takes IDs as arguments, not SQL. It's trying to use that second argument as an ID, which clearly won't work.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Comment: Interestingly `User.find(4, :select => 'first_name, last_name')` works on Rails 3.2.19. It must depend on the version of Rails you're using.

Comment: Oh wow, I suppose I was looking at old docs. You're absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

`find` only finds records by id.  You can pass in an array of id's but it doesn't take any options.  So it thinks the hash you are passing is an id, and it bombs because it can't find a record with that ID.  I think what you want is something like:

```
@user = User.find(4)
fname = @user.fname
lname = @user.lname
```

Comment: I thought maybe I could use something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10256469/4630523

Comment: @wolf3D If you read the comment in that SO question, you'll see "This is no longer correct and is not supported in Rails 4. Answer needs updating." .find is meant to find a single record. .where is meant to find more than one record.

Comment: @aaron-coding I was using it to obtain the record of a single user. Thanks anyway!