# Rails query: find first record by id and select only specified attributes for that record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find a `Blog` by its `:id`, and then `select` only a couple of its attributes.

Example:

```
# Doesn't work and I don't know why
# I want to grab the first blog with this id, and then grab only selected attributes
blog = Blog.find(10).select(:id, :title, :date)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630028/how-to-find-a-record-by-id-and-select-few-columns-ruby-on-rails) suggests to use `where` instead of `find`.  But to my knowledge `where` in my scenario is inefficient because it continues searching the database for more matches even after it finds the only record I want to grab.

How can I specify to grab the first record it finds by the id, and then grab only the selected attributes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`blog = Blog.select(:id, :title, :date).find(1)`

Comment: Ah!  I guess order matters here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@nsave's answer is probably your best bet.

If for whatever reason, you want to keep your order (of `select` going later), you can do the following:

`blog = Blog.where(id: 10).select(:id, :title, :date).first`

or

`blog = Blog.where(id: 10).select(:id, :title, :date)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

### pick (Rails 6+)

Rails 6 introduced a new [pick](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pick) method.

So, now your problem can be solved as

```rb
Blog.where(id: 1).pick(:id, :title, :date)
```

It is even more efficient than

```rb
Blog.select(:id, :title, :date).find(1)
```

since, it will only load the column value(s), and will not load the ActiveRecord object.

For more details, please, follow this [link to docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pick).

Also, there is a [reference to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31941).